# Ajax exibe mensagem e esconde logo em seguida

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Este meu código está meio bugado, a função dele é exibir a mensagem e deixar lá até que atualize a página, mas está sumindo.

```
$('form#yes').on('click', function() {
    function isyes() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: 'vote/yes',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(vote) {
                if (vote['computed'] === true) {
                    $('.text-success').show();
                    $('.text-success').html(vote['message']);
                } else if (vote['computed'] === false) {
                    $('.text-danger').show();
                    $('.text-danger').html(vote['message']);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    isyes();
})
```

Por que? Está com algum reload e eu não estou vendo?

Comment: Poste seu código html para ajudar na resposta.

Comment: Tente colocar a função `isyes` fora do `$('form#yes').on('click', function() {});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que pode ser algum tipo de incompatibilidade com a function, já que você está criando um function dentro de outra, o mais correto seria apenas chamar a function no evento click:

```
function isyes() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: 'vote/yes',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(vote) {
                if (vote['computed'] === true) {
                    $('.text-success').show();
                    $('.text-success').html(vote['message']);
                } else if (vote['computed'] === false) {
                    $('.text-danger').show();
                    $('.text-danger').html(vote['message']);
                }
            }
        });
    }

$('form#yes').on('click', function() {
    isyes();
})
```

Ou deixar apenas o ajax:

```
$('form#yes').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: 'vote/yes',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(vote) {
                if (vote['computed'] === true) {
                    $('.text-success').show();
                    $('.text-success').html(vote['message']);
                } else if (vote['computed'] === false) {
                    $('.text-danger').show();
                    $('.text-danger').html(vote['message']);
                }
            }
        });
})
```

Caso não seja este o problema verifique no console se por algum acaso esse ajax esteja sendo chamado 2 vezes, pois quando se utiliza ajax para load, as vezes a function fica guardada em cache na execução atual fazendo com que o clique chame a função 2 vezes (a do seu codigo e a que ficou em cache) ai buga tudo, mas ainda continuo recomendando a retirada dessa function de dentro do evento click.

Comment: no console não mostra nada, porém não é esta a solução.

Comment: No console mostraria apenas se houvesse erro, mas na aba de "network" mostra todas as requisições feitas, verifique se não está fazendo 2 requisições quando se clica no botão. Isso pode estar fazendo com que na 1ª Request a condição seja TRUE e a segunda Request FALSE, no sistema que estou desenvolvendo acontece muito isso.

Comment: O correto do ajax seria não dar reload, aqui está pedindo pra confirmar o reenvio das informações no formulário. What? Não estou entendendo.

Comment: Se esta função é chamada quando o botão "SUBMIT" é clicado coloque dentro do evento click um " return false; ", ou retire o botão submit e coloque um buttom simples, caso contrário ele executará o reload.

Comment: Haha cara valeu funcionou!!